# Recursive type - lifetime issues

Tags: rust, reference, lifetime, borrow-checker, borrowing

I think I partially understand the lifetime concepts, but I have an issue in a recursive type definition:

```rust
struct Person<'a> {
    name: String,
    children: Vec<&'a mut Person<'a>>,
    birth: String,
    death: String,
    religion: String,
    genre: String,
}

impl Person<'_> {
    fn add_children(&'_ mut self, p: &'_ mut Person<'_>) {
        self.children.push(p);
    }
}
```

The compiler says:

```
error[E0312]: lifetime of reference outlives lifetime of borrowed content...
  --> src/lib.rs:12:28
   |
12 |         self.children.push(p);
   |                            ^
   |
note: ...the reference is valid for the lifetime `'_` as defined on the impl at 10:13...
  --> src/lib.rs:10:13
   |
10 | impl Person<'_> {
   |             ^^
note: ...but the borrowed content is only valid for the anonymous lifetime #2 defined on the method body at 11:5
  --> src/lib.rs:11:5
   |
11 |     fn add_children(&'_ mut self, p: &'_ mut Person<'_>) {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:12:28
   |
12 |         self.children.push(p);
   |                            ^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected mutable reference `&mut Person<'_>`
              found mutable reference `&mut Person<'_>`
note: the anonymous lifetime #3 defined on the method body at 11:5...
  --> src/lib.rs:11:5
   |
11 |     fn add_children(&'_ mut self, p: &'_ mut Person<'_>) {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...does not necessarily outlive the lifetime `'_` as defined on the impl at 10:13
  --> src/lib.rs:10:13
   |
10 | impl Person<'_> {
   |             ^^

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:12:28
   |
12 |         self.children.push(p);
   |                            ^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected mutable reference `&mut Person<'_>`
              found mutable reference `&mut Person<'_>`
note: the lifetime `'_` as defined on the impl at 10:13...
  --> src/lib.rs:10:13
   |
10 | impl Person<'_> {
   |             ^^
note: ...does not necessarily outlive the anonymous lifetime #3 defined on the method body at 11:5
  --> src/lib.rs:11:5
   |
11 |     fn add_children(&'_ mut self, p: &'_ mut Person<'_>) {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

How is that? In my understanding, `self` and `p` have the same lifetime.

I want it to be a `Vec<&mut Person>` because I have a `HashMap<String, Person>` with every person having its children initialized to `Vec::new()`. I want to pass references to the `Vec` so it does not copy the whole person's data when updating children.

Comment: You'll see that the answer now has a lot more useful context for your specific case, which is why we wanted to know why. What you wanted is _extremely_ limited and is covered by a lot of [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423).

Comment: I missed that one, thank you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'_` tells the compiler to infer the lifetime for you but in this case it's inferring a bunch of different anonymous lifetimes. Since the lifetime of `Person` is directly dependent on the lifetimes of its `children` you should make that explicit in your implementation, and once you do it compiles:

```rust
struct Person<'a> {
    name: String,
    children: Vec<&'a mut Person<'a>>,
    birth: String,
    death: String,
    religion: String,
    genre: String,
}

impl<'a> Person<'a> {
    fn add_children(&mut self, p: &'a mut Person<'a>) {
        self.children.push(p);
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cfa583e0cebe7f6057c50718154d67a4)

While the above compiles you'll find in practice that it's incredibly restrictive and hard to work with, if it's okay to have clones of `Person`s you'll have a much easier time working with this struct instead:

```rust
struct Person {
    children: Vec<Person>,
    // other fields
}
```

If you *need* to share `Person`s between multiple `children` vectors while being able to mutate them you should go with:

```rust
struct Person {
    children: Vec<Rc<RefCell<Person>>>,
    // other fields
}
```

If you're storing all `Person`s in a `HashMap<String, Person>` where the keys are unique and immutable you could also maintain each `children` vector like so:

```rust
struct Person {
    children: Vec<String>, // keys for HashMap<String, Person>
    // other fields
}
```

Comment: I'd also add that one way to avoid ownership issues is to have a store that contains all references of a type and a struct containing structure with ids. This way you can structure your data by keeping identifiers in a recursive struct like Vec<PersonID> but be able to get e ref of those ids from the store whenever you need.